# Docker sets wrong owner for MongoDB mounted volume

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple NodeJs app with MongoDB using Docker(docker-compose). Everything works just fine, but Mongo's mounted volume is created under ownership of user 999.

Docker is executed under the permission of a non-root user.

Here is the mounted volume permissions info:

```
drwxr-sr-x   4      999 www-data 4,0K Aug  5 21:56 mongo-data
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    api:
       .....
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: "mongodb"
        environment:
            - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
            - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
        volumes:
            - ./mongo-data:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null
volumes:
    mongo-data:
```

Next time when executing: *docker-compose up -d --build* will throw this error:

*ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?*

If the ownership of the mounted volume is changed, everything is back to normal until next time.

I mention that I previously used this kind of configuration with MySQL and Redis, but I never encountered this issue.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This also creates issues in managing those files on the host, such as backing up those files as a non-privileged user, which might be something one wants on a developer PC.

**Here's the actual solution**!

You can:

```
docker run --user some-other-user-id:some-group-id
```

or, in docker-compose, here's a minimal example:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    user: '1000:1000'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

After running this, looking at the data directory, it contains only user/group of 1000. Of course, set this to whatever you find appropriate.

I found that it was necessary to create the directory first under the user that is specified. The docker-compose runs as root, if I'm not mistaken, and the directory gets owned by root and that creates mayhem.

So,

```
mkdir data
docker-compose up
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu based images, `999` will be the first possible system assigned UID for unknown users, with further IDs counting down.

What this could mean is that the directory you are mounting might be a network path or might be copied from another machine, both leading to the user being unknown on your machine, leading to a system assigned UID.

Note that you can use the `ADD --chown X:Y` Syntax to add files under a user with a defined user ID.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the previous answer, to avoid issues like this in the future, you could consider using managed volumes rather than a specific directory in your filesystem. Keeps all those weird files out of sight, and avoids odd permissions issues like this. Here's my Docker Compose setup for Mongo:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/local-docker-db/blob/master/mongo/docker-compose.yml#L6

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes across this again => You can either patch or re-build the official docker-image with minimal changes to use a custom UID/GID.

Example for patching it using docker-compose:

```bash
# dockerfile for patching

# replace these:
#  mongodb_version_min: '5.0.17'
#  mongodb_user_id: '1200'

FROM mongo:{{ mongodb_version_min }}
RUN groupmod --gid {{ mongodb_user_id }} mongodb; \
    usermod --uid {{ mongodb_user_id }} mongodb; \
    chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db /data/configdb
```

```yaml
# replace these:
#  mongodb_version_min: '5.0.17'
#  mongodb_patch_file: '/etc/containers/mongodb_dockerfile'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'local/mongodb:{{ mongodb_version_min }}'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: '{{ mongodb_patch_file }}'
```

You can find full examples for re-building and patching using 'docker-compose', 'docker build' and 'Ansible' in this repository:

- https://github.com/superstes/docker-mongodb-uid

Comment: the linked resource is small enough that I'd have inlined it into your post body. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587